# Подмена сообщений websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, chrome-extension

Задача заключается в том, чтобы модифицировать входящие сообщения на websocket с помощью content script. Как это можно сделать? Слышал, что в таких случаях помогает подмена конструктора websocket - как конкретно нужно это делать?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что это поможет в случае если страница не ваша (вряд ли получится подменить), но вот как это можно реализовать на своей странице:

- `origWS = WebSocket` сохраняем оригинальный объект;
- `class WS {...}` реализуем замещающий класс
- `WebSocket = WS;` осуществляем замену

[image: скриншот]

код на клиенте:

```
<body>
  <form name="publish">
    <input type="text" name="message">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
  <div id="subscribe"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  const origWS = WebSocket;

  class WS {
    constructor(address){
      this.socket = new origWS("ws://localhost:8081"); 
      this.socket.onmessage = this.onMessage.bind(this);
      this._onmessage = 123;
    }
    set onmessage(value){
      this._onmessage = value;
    }
    get onmessage(){
       return this._onmessage;
    }
    send(outgoingMessage){
      this.socket.send(outgoingMessage);
    }
    onMessage(event) {
      if (this._onmessage){
        const data = `перехвачено: ${event.data}`
        const newEvent = {...event, data}
        this._onmessage(newEvent);
      }
    }
  }
  
  WebSocket = WS;

  // создать подключение
  var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");
  // отправить сообщение из формы publish
  document.forms.publish.onsubmit = function() {
    var outgoingMessage = this.message.value;
   socket.send(outgoingMessage);
    return false;
  };
  // обработчик входящих сообщений
  socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var incomingMessage = event.data;
    showMessage(incomingMessage);
  };
  // показать сообщение в div#subscribe
  function showMessage(message) {
    var messageElem = document.createElement('div');
    messageElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    document.getElementById('subscribe').appendChild(messageElem);
  }
</script>
</body>
```

код на сервере:

```
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// подключённые клиенты
var clients = {};

// WebSocket-сервер на порту 8081
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
  port: 8081
});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {

  var id = Math.random();
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("новое соединение " + id);

  ws.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('получено сообщение ' + message);

    for (var key in clients) {
      clients[key].send(message);
    }
  });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('соединение закрыто ' + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119885/discussion-on-answer-by-daniil-loban---websocket).